# Puppeteer often fails waitForNavigation with Timeout error on Twitter

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am playing around with Puppeteer for Twitter automation. I have discovered that often the navigation will timeout. For example:

```
puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
    try {
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto('https://twitter.com/home');
        
        // This sometimes fails with timeout error
        await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

        if (page.url() === 'https://twitter.com/login') {
            await login(page);
        }

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

The page will just hang and I'll get the error `TimeoutError`

I have tried changing the `waitUntil` parameter and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I have also set `await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);` this of course stops the error appearing but the page just never responds.

Has anyone else faced this problem? Is Twitter detecting me? Or have I missed something? I am using puppeteer-extra with puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth using the default settings.

Comment: (1) what is the ratio of succesfull visits and timeouts? (e.g. 1 time out of 10 visits) (2) have you tried to make a `page.screenshot` on the timeouts? (3) have you tried `page.waitForSelector` rather than waitForNavigation? (after a `page.goto` I wouldn't expect new navigation events, that can make the scraper unrelaible)

Comment: You don't have to wait for network idle, just wait for the login form.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, while waiting for the `networkidle2` you can stuck from time to time as it some requests can occur, it's much better to wait for a particular element. Also, just interested why don't to use the API https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs to get/update/monitor or whatever is needed? Or you need to test the exact twitter UI?